# Django docxtpl не открывает сохраненный шаблон .docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docx, python-docx

Всех приветствую!

Пытаюсь вывести в документ поля из модели.
На выходе получаю нужный файл, но он не открывается: пишет что-то вроде **"невозможно открыть файл из-за проблем с его содержанием".**   Нужные переменные стоят в шаблоне в соответсвующих тегах {{ }}.

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from .models import Resource, Person
 from django.http import HttpResponse, FileResponse
 from docxtpl import DocxTemplate


# функиця создания бланка
def resource_create_blank(request, id):
    doc = DocxTemplate('изготовление.docx')
    person = Person.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {
        'surname': person.surname,
        'name': person.name,
        'patronymic': person.patronymic,
    }

    doc.render(context)
    doc.save("Заявка.docx")
    return render(request, 'services/create/done.html')
```

В чем моя ошибка? Какие есть варианты решения проблемы?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ошибку.
В модели пользователя была создана функция - **patronymic**

И для того, чтобы ей воспользоваться  при сохранении в файл, необходимо:

```
...    
'patronymic': str(person.patronymic()),
...
```

Вопрос решен.